# Can I turn ReSharper TODOs into compiler warnings?

Tags: c#, resharper, compiler-warnings

With ReSharper installed, comments like this

```
// TODO: fix this glaring defect
```

are highlighted and show up in the To-do Explorer window. Is there any way to turn these into compiler warnings?

Comment: Why highlight all the glaring defects, why not fix them right away? :) Could you put the `#warning` and `TODO` on separate lines?

Comment: It's a large codebase and they aren't all _my_ TODOs, but I'm interested in raising their visibility so we can get them fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently possible, as todo items are only searched for in the contexts given by the checkboxes (so only in comments, strings, and identifiers at the time of writing). Support for what you want is on the JetBrains bugtracker as [RSRP-71440 #warnings can't be captured in the TODO list](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-71440) - note that in May 2011, the target fix version was pushed out from 5.1 to an unspecificed future version.

Comment: That's kind of a different answer... that's making `#warnings` show up in the TODO explorer. I want TODOs to turn into warnings.

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean whoops, thought process ran away with me. I'll leave this here for posterity.

Answer (score 6):

Why not get best of both worlds:

```
#warning // TODO: fix this glaring defect.
```

Comment: #warning causes Resharper to not recognize TODO's

Comment: Don't know about Resharper, but TODO is still picked up by the regular VS Task List with such a construction